# Where is this Capistrano deploy task found?

Tags: capistrano3, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm going through the [Capistrano flow examples](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/flow/) because my boss wants to remove Capistrano from the deployment process, don't ask me why, so I want to replicate the process but on a manual basis  Anyways I'm looking for the `deploy:set_shared_assets` task but I can't find it within the [git repo](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano). Does anyone know where this is located?

I just want to find out what each step does under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking this https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/docs/documentation/getting-started/flow/index.markdown, maybe it's not up to date. Here is the last occurrence that I found https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/v1.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake